# How to find the time complexity of dfs+backtracking algorithms?

Tags: java, algorithm, recursion, time-complexity, depth-first-search

I am trying to solve this problem on leetcode https://leetcode.com/problems/factor-combinations/description/

> Numbers can be regarded as product of its factors. For example
>
> 8 = 2 x 2 x 2;   = 2 x 4.

Write a function that takes an integer n and return all possible combinations of its factors.

while I am able to write the code using dfs approach , I am having hard time in driving its worst case time complexity in terms of input. Can anyone please help?

```
 public List<List<Integer>> getFactors(int n) {
        List<List<Integer>> result = new ArrayList<List<Integer>>();
        List<Integer> current = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        getFactorsHelper(n,2,current,result);
        return result;
    }
    
    
    public void getFactorsHelper(int n,int start,List<Integer> current, List<List<Integer>> result){
        if(n<=1 && current.size()>1){
            result.add(new ArrayList<>(current));
            return;
            
        }
        for(int i=start;i<=n;i++){
          
            if(n%i==0) {
                current.add(i);
                getFactorsHelper(n/i,i,current,result);
                current.remove(current.size()-1);
            }            
            
        }
        
    }
```

Comment: Time complexity with respect to what variable?

Comment: with respect to input n

Comment: Ok, but bear in mind that it's going to be wildly fluctuating - for example 127 has only one output, whereas 128 has loads.

Comment: yup. I am intersted in worst case complexity.

Comment: What does "worst case" mean here?  (I'm not trying to be difficult, I'm trying to point out that your question may not make sense as it's currently posed.)

Comment: The variable should be the number of factors.

Comment: Ok, I edited the question . worst case meaning , maximum num of recursive calls/num of iterations this may take while computing number of combination factors for a given n.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I computed complexity of your code like this:

Let's consider the `runtime` of `getFactorsHelper(n,2)` is function `T(n)`.

In bellow portion you have a loop with `i` index.

```
for(int i=start;i<=n;i++){    
            if(n%i==0) {
                current.add(i);
                getFactorsHelper(n/i,i,current,result);
                current.remove(current.size()-1);
            }              
        }
```

The `n` is divided by `i` in each iteration. So we have:

**(first iteration)**

```
getFactorsHelper(n/2,2,current,result) = T(n/2)
```

**(second iteration)**

```
getFactorsHelper(n/3,3,current,result) <= getFactorsHelper(n/3,2,current,result) = T(n/3)
```

**(third iteration)**

```
getFactorsHelper(n/4,4,current,result) <= getFactorsHelper(n/4,2,current,result) 
= T(n/4)
```

**...**

**(final iteration)**

```
getFactorsHelper(n/n,n,current,result) <= getFactorsHelper(n/n,2,current,result) = T(n/n) = T(1)
```

**total cost**

```
T(n) <= T(n/2) + T(n/3) + T(n/4) + ... + T(1)
```

**Solving recursive function**

[image: order]

I hope this can help you.

Comment: Thanks Ali for detailing out the answer. If I have to understand in a more simplified manner .first time when getFactorsHelper gets called , there are total of n possible iterations (because of 2 to n for loop) . The part where I am getting confused to figure out the work done in each iteration.

Comment: @KBR Sorry, I made a mistake in calculating the loop order!!. I solved it again. Please see it.

Comment: Thanks Ali. so its O(nlogn) ..right ? sorry for asking this as some of the mathematical symbols I am trying to recall from my college days

Comment: @KBR Yes `O(nlnn) = O(nlogn)`.

Comment: hi @AliSoltani Can you help with [this solution](https://discuss.leetcode.com/topic/30752/my-short-java-solution-which-is-easy-to-understand) ? The solution that KBR posts takes about 210ms in leetcode, while following only takes 2ms. Based on your analysis the slow solution is O(nlogn), so the quick one should be O(n) ?

Answer (score 0):

Not able to post the solution in the comment. Post as another answer here @AliSoltani
https://discuss.leetcode.com/topic/30752/my-short-java-solution-which-is-easy-to-understand

```
public class Solution {
public List<List<Integer>> getFactors(int n) {
    List<List<Integer>> ret = new LinkedList<List<Integer>>();
    if(n <= 3)  return ret;
    List<Integer> path = new LinkedList<Integer>();
    getFactors(2, n, path, ret);
    return ret;
}

private void getFactors(int start, int n, List<Integer> path, List<List<Integer>> ret){
   for(int i = start; i <= Math.sqrt(n); i++){
       if(n % i == 0 && n/i >= i){  // The previous factor is no bigger than the next
           path.add(i);
           path.add(n/i);
           ret.add(new LinkedList<Integer>(path));
           path.remove(path.size() - 1);
           getFactors(i, n/i, path, ret);
           path.remove(path.size() - 1);
       }
   }
}}
```